# Yet another command-line argument with spaces question

Tags: scala, apache-spark, command-line, spaces

I am executing a spark job, via spark-submit using a wrapper script and a parameter file. The parameter file contains some config information in addition to a set of set of command line arguments needed by the spark job.

The parameter file, params.sh, look like this:

```
MODE="query"
QUERYCOND="Id==1 and customer==2"
PACKAGE="com.etl"
CLASS="ExecSparkETL"
DRIVER_CLASS_PATH="/home/jars/ojdbc8.jar"
JARS="/home/jars/ojdbc8.jar"
JAR="/home/jars/etl-scala_2.11-1.0.0.jar"
ARGS="$MODE \"$CUSTOM\""
```

The wrapper script, exec.sh, contains this:

```
source params.sh
spark2-submit \
--class ${PACKAGE}.${CLASS} \
--queue root.me \
--deploy-mode client \
--master yarn \
--driver-class-path $DRIVER_CLASS_PATH \
--jars $JARS \
--conf spark.network.timeout=1200000 \
$JAR \
$ARGS
```

If I echo $ARGS from the script the result is what I should be passing to the scala jar as two args, one of them having spaces in the arg which is wrapped in double-quotes:

```
query "Id==1 and customer==2"
```

But when I execute and print those two args from within the scala program I get:

```
arg1: query
arg2: "Id==1
```

So it is somehow not parsing my double-quote wrapped argument correctly.

Now if I execute the program without assigning the program paramters to the script variable ARGS, it works as expected:

```
source params.sh
spark2-submit \
--class ${PACKAGE}.${CLASS} \
--queue root.me \
--deploy-mode client \
--master yarn \
--driver-class-path $DRIVER_CLASS_PATH \
--jars $JARS \
--conf spark.network.timeout=1200000 \
$JAR \
query "Id==1 and customer==2"
```

Results...

```
arg1: query
arg2: "Id==1 and customer==2"
```

So it doesn't seem to like the fact that the two parameters passed to the scala program are stored in a variable, like it is dropping the double-quote wrap from the parameter that contains spaces.

Any ideas on how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

[I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- the solution is to use an array:

```sh
source params.sh

spark_args=(
    --class "${PACKAGE}.${CLASS}"
    --queue root.me
    --deploy-mode client
    --master yarn
    --driver-class-path "$DRIVER_CLASS_PATH"
    --jars "$JARS"
    --conf spark.network.timeout=1200000
    "$JAR"
    "$MODE"
    "$CUSTOM"
)

spark2-submit "${spark_args[@]}"
```

Note how all the variables are quoted.

Arrays are available in bash/zsh/ksh but not plain sh.

Comment: That seems like a great solution but the problem is the wrapper script is used by several dozen other spark programs, with various numbers of command-line arguments. Each program has its own parameter file with an ARGS variable contain the programs' args. This is the first case where I need to pass an argument with spaces, so ideally I would like this to fit within that framework. I guess what I just don't understand is why the ARGS variable seems to mess with the double-quote enclosed parameter containing spaces. Is there an easy fix to get the ARGS variable to expand correctly?

Comment: No. The double quotes in the $ARGS variable are just plain characters in a string. You want to smash $MODE and $CUSTOM into a single string, and then you want the shell to extract the original values out of that string. The shell can't do it, unless you use `eval` which is generally not recommended.

Comment: Given your question, I don't understand why you must use the $ARGS variable instead of $MODE and $CUSTOM individually.